# SIM868 AT+CIPGSMLOC returns latitude and longitude location as 0.000000

Tags: gsm

I am unable to get any location data from SIM868 module using the command

```
AT+CIPGSMLOC=1,1
It returns 0.000000,0.000000,2019/12/23,08:50:39
```

I have internet enabled using AT+SAPBR=1,1 command.
However I get proper location data when I use the command AT+CLBS=4,1
Havent found any relevant info in the AT command Manual v1.10.

I had AT+CIPGSMLOC=1,1 command working correctly on a sim800L module.

Comment: Not enough satellites. Take it outside or put it in a window.

Comment: AT+CIPGSMLOC command is used to give gsm location which gives a location as soon as internet is connected. This location is very coarse and is believed to be the location of a cell tower. Which means it has no connection with satellites.